# Modifying an ext2 File Structure in Linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel, inode, ext2

For a university assignment, we have to modify the ext2 file system to store files in the inode's block pointers if it's smaller than 60 bytes, and move to regular block storage once the file grows larger than that.

I have, what might admittedly be a silly question, but I was wondering if anyone with experience working in the ext2fs might be able to tell me whether the inode structure itself would have to be modified to accomplish this task?

And would modification of the inode, if it were required, impede the general running of the ext2 system?

Answer (score -1):

for better understanding of any filesystem in Linux I recommend 'Linux kernel development' 3rd edition by Robert Love. (The Virtual Filesystem part)
after that you can read GNU documentations about ext2 filesystem. 
and then start reading e2fsprogs. this is the tool for creating ext filesystems. if you want to modify filesystem structure, you need to build modified filesystem first. finally read the actual source code of kernel's ext2 driver.
keep in mind that there is no short way to do this. you should understand Linux VFS completely. 
and one other thing.. when reading source files keep in mind that the most important parts of the code are data structures that act like objects.
use source code reading tools listed by GNU like cscope.
and yes! modification of inode structure CAN cause many sorts of problems.

good luck :)

Comment: [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: Link Only answers are highly discouraged as links may expire in future.

Comment: what is this? I just wanted to help someone find the answer for his question. I don't really care about this commenting and deleting games you guys play.. and links in GNU project official site are reliable enough.